# How to fix still reachable error in valgrind?

Tags: c++, valgrind

-----update-----

I managed to fix the issue by not exiting mid-function but returning to main and exiting there.

Can you explain **why** it worked?

tnx

---

I keep getting still reachable valgrind error on my code.

Already tried:

1. close file before exit, and before function readCSV ends
2. declare iss once, and using iss.str, iss.clear

(all destructors are default)

I think this function is causing me problems. I's called from the main function, and reads the csv file into a deque:

```
static std::deque<Fractal *> readCSV(const std::string &path)
{
    std::deque<Fractal *> fractals;
    std::ifstream ifs(path);
    if (ifs.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << INV_INPUT << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    std::string line;
    while (getline(ifs, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::string arg;
        int type, height;
        getline(iss, arg, ',');
        type = strToN(arg);//parse int from string, -1 if not a valid integer
        getline(iss, arg, ',');
        height = strToN(arg);
        if (height <= 0 || height > MAX_HEIGHT)
        {
            std::cerr << INV_INPUT << std::endl;
            deleteFractalArr(fractals);
            exit(1);
        }
        if (getline(iss, arg, ','))
        {
            std::cerr << INV_INPUT << std::endl;
            deleteFractalArr(fractals);
            exit(1);
        }

        switch (type)
        {
            case 1:
                fractals.push_front(new SCarpet(height));
                break;
            case 2:
                fractals.push_front(new SSieve(height));
                break;
            case 3:
                fractals.push_front(new CDust(height));
                break;
            default:
                std::cerr << INV_INPUT << std::endl;
                deleteFractalArr(fractals);
                exit(1);
        }
    }
    return fractals;
}
```

the deleteFractalArr is as follows:

```
static void deleteFractalArr(const std::deque<Fractal *> &fractals)
{
    for (Fractal *f:fractals)
    {
        delete f;
        f = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `deleteFractalArr` function, the assignment `f = nullptr` doesn't really do anything.

Comment: And for Valgrind errors, please first of all try to create a [mcve] to show us, and include the full Valgrind output, and mark out the lines it mentions in the example code.

Comment: Unreachable memory is an error. Reachable typically isn't, unless it's memory that's no longer being actively used but is still being referred to.

Comment: If you run Valgrind with --memcheck:show-reachable=yes plus you have a debug build then the Valgrind output should include the line of your code where the memory was allocated.

Can you post your Valgrind output?



On some systems, there may be some still reachable dynamic memory allocated by the OS, C runtime or C++ runtime libraries, but that doesn't seem to be your case.